# Are there any browsers with a JSX compiler built in?

Tags: reactjs

Can we run react with `jsx` without installing the `jsx` compiler?

Comment: No, there are no browsers that provide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no browsers with a JSX compiler.

Source: https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/are-there-any-browsers-with-a-jsx-compiler-built-in/385750

However, you can use JSX without React: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-jsx-without-react-21d23346e5dc